# How do I explain how the analytic function looks like?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I have the following problem.

> We have given $g$ to be an analytic function such that for $|z-z_0|<R$ we have $$|g(z)|\leq M$$. We assume that $g$ have a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$. Then I have shown what $$|g(z)|\leq \frac{M}{R^m}|z-z_0|^m~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$ Now I assume that above I $(1)$ we have equality. I need to explain how this function looks like.

My claim was the following:

> **Claim** Equality in $(1)$ holds for some $z\neq z_0$ iff $$g(z)=\lambda (z-z_0)^m$$ for some constant $\lambda \in \Bbb{C}$.

I wanted to prove my claim now.

$\Leftarrow$Let us assume that $\lambda\in \Bbb{C}$ is a constant and $g(z)=\lambda (z-z_0)^m$. Then since $
|z-z_0|<R$ we have $|g(z)|<\lambda R^m =:M$. This means that $\lambda=\frac{M}{R^m}$. Then $$|g(z)|=|\lambda||z-z_0|^m=\frac{M}{R^m}|z-z_0|^m$$as we wanted.

$\Rightarrow$ Here assume that $$|g(z)|=\frac{M}{R^m}|z-z_0|^m$$ when $|z-z_0|<R$. Here I know that I need to show that $g(z)=\lambda(z-z_0)^m$ but I don't see why this is true, I thought maybe one could do it using contradiction but then I don't see how I should chose my $g$. My prof. told me that my claim is correct so I really only need to prove this.

Could maybe someone help me with this direction?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $|h(z)|$ is constant in an open and connected domain then $h(z)$ is constant there. You can make use $\log \,h(z)$ locally or the Cauchy-Riemann conditions for $h(z).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sorry I don't get it. Is this hint useful for $\Rightarrow$ implication? If yes could you explain this a bit more

Comment: My idea now was to assume that $|g(z)|=\frac{M}{R^m}|z-z_0|^m$ and that $g(z)=\lambda (z-z_0)^m+\lambda '(z-z_0)^{m'}$ where $m'>m$ This can be done since $g$ is analytic. Using the equality from above and my $g$ I would get $|\lambda+\lambda'(z-z_0)^{m'-m}|=\frac{M}{R^m}$. But I'm not sure if this helps me

Comment: Do you assume equality in (1) for all points $z$  with $|z-z_0|<R$ ?

Comment: now only for some $z\neq _0$

Comment: Is there a possibility to use my idea from the above comment or do I have to show it completely different?

Comment: Then you can apply the maximum modulus principle, as the ratio $g(z)/(z-z_0)^m$ attains its maximum inside the circle. Hence it must be constant. The ratio is analytic also at $z_0.$

Comment: Sorry so I want to resume all to be sure I understood everything correctly. so I assume the equality in $(1)$ and I define $g$ as I did in the third comment right? Then I know that $\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}=\lambda +\lambda'(z-z_0)^{m^-m}$ now I need to apply the maximum modulus principle to this function to get that it is constant right? But where do I then use the equality in $(1)$?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc So I think my last comment is completely wrong isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134938/discussion-between-ryszard-szwarc-and-aprozz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $$|g(z)|\le {M\over R^m}|z-z_0|^m,\qquad |z-z_0|<R$$ and
$$|g(w)|= {M\over R^m}|w-z_0|^m$$ for a point $w,$ $|w-z_0|<R.$
Consider the function $$h(z)={g(z)\over (z-z_0)^m},\qquad |z-z_0|<R.$$
This function is analytic in $|z-z_0|<R,$ as $z_0$ is a removable singularity. Moroever $$|h(z)|\le {M\over R^m},\qquad |h(w)|={M\over R^m} $$ From the maximum modulus principle the function $h(z)$ is constant, i.e. $h(z)\equiv \lambda$ for a complex number $\lambda. $  Thus $g(z)=\lambda {M\over R^m}(z-z_0)^m.$